# What can I use to allow users to send transactions through a website?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, javascript

I am trying to build a website that will allow multiple users to send Ethereum transactions without having to install a node. My server is running a node, which is configured to accept requests from any internet address, and it seems that I should be able to connect to the node from any device through a web browser. Is the Ethereum JavaScript API useful to doing this? Thank you!

Comment: Though possible, allowing RPC connections from any hosts is discouraged due to security implications. The usual pattern is to have server-side software that speaks to Ethereum node behind a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, you can use `web3.ETH.sendTransaction` to Sends a transaction to the network.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject [, callback])
```

Example

```
// compiled solidity source code using https://chriseth.github.io/cpp-ethereum/
var code = "603d80600c6000396000f3007c01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000350463c6888fa18114602d57005b6007600435028060005260206000f3";

web3.eth.sendTransaction({data: code}, function(err, address) {
  if (!err)
    console.log(address); // "0x7f9fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2eb7b11a91385"
});
```

Comment: This question does not answer regarding if you need or don't need a node running on users' side

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Why not? web3 can connect to any node right?

Comment: Are you saying one should run publicly facing Ethereum node allowing RPC connections from any host? As far as I know running public RPC interface is highly discouraged due to security implications.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa yeah, i am aware of that. OP is not asking or seems to be worried about that.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your node, then create a public facing api that accepts signed raw transactions input. You could do this with hooked web3 and your users could use [eth-lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) by ConsenSys.

`signing.signTx(keystore, pwDerivedKey, rawTx, signingAddress, hdPathString)`

Signs a transaction with the private key corresponding to signingAddress.

**Inputs**

- keystore: An instance of the keystore with which to sign the TX with.
- pwDerivedKey: the users password derived key (Uint8Array)
- rawTx: Hex-string defining an RLP-encoded raw transaction.
- signingAddress: hex-string defining the address to send the transaction from.
- hdPathString: (Optional) A path at which to create the encryption keys.

**Return value**

Hex-string corresponding to the RLP-encoded raw transaction.